# How to get the sum an array of strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, floating-point, sum

I have an array of decimal numbers as strings, I need to get the sum of the array, I have tried iterating over the array and changing each number to a float but that just returns a whole number each time and I need the sum to be a decimal.  What data type should I change the string to, and the best way to get the sum of the array would be helpful.

Comment: What is "array decimal numbers as strings"? Is it an array, number, or string? You need to improve your English to make yourself understood.

Comment: It looks like you have tried something, but is not 100% clear what that is. The easiest thing to do is show some code, including an example input, and what you would like the output to be.

Comment: When you ask a question like this, it helps if you show sample input and the output you want, plus code you've written to try to solve the problem. Without those things it really looks like you're fishing for someone to write the code for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to do

```
array.map(&:to_f).reduce(:+)
```

Explanation :-

```
# it give you back all the Float instances from String instances
array.map(&:to_f)
# same as
array.map { |string| string.to_f }
array.map(&:to_f).reduce(:+)
# is a shorthand of 
array.map(&:to_f).reduce { |sum, float| sum + float }
```

Documentation of [`#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: Nice answer. I think the OP would benefit from some explanation.

Comment: ["If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for `memo`, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of `memo`."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) so you don't need to specify the initial `0.0`.

Comment: @muistooshort It happened somehow. I don't know why :(. But anyway, I have corrected it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Note `[].map(&:to_f).reduce(:+) #=> nil`, whereas 
`[].map(&:to_f).reduce(0.0, :+) => 0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

- First we put string of numbers into Array of strings
- Second we change the whole block into numbers
- Then we sum it all up, if Array is empty then we do not get nil but 0

## String into sum

```
str='1,2,3,4'.split(',').map(&:to_i).inject(0,:+) #1+2+3+4=10
```

## Array of numbers into sum

```
 num=[1,2,3,4].inject(0,:+)#=>10
 p str
 p num
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["12.4", "48.2"]
a.inject(0) {|s,e| s.to_f + e.to_f } #=> 60.6
```

`inject` lets you accumulate a value across. Documentation of [`#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either of following statements:

```
array.map(&:to_f).reduce(:+)
array.sum(&:to_f)
```

Comment: `.sum` is defined in `active_support` so it's `rails`. If you want to use only ruby then the first statement.